# Backward compatibility in Enum Singleton vs Class

Tags: java, enums, singleton, backwards-compatibility

I have heard multiple times that using enums is the best way to implement a singleton in Java, and I know the reasons why.

My question is, Is there any concern/disadvantage in terms of backward compatibility? Or to phrase it differently: Does a singleton implemented with a class offer any advantage in regards to backward compatibility?

Thanks.

EDIT: Let's say I want to evolve the API and I'd want to minimize impact to existing clients. Would there be any advantage/disadvantage to using an enum vs a class for a singleton?

Comment: Backwards compatibility with what, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

a simple and effective implementation of singleton in java:

```
public class A {
private A(){}
public static final A instance = new A();
.....
}
```

Comment: Or you can do `enum A { instance } `